# Change range in running macro

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to change range in running macro?

For example if I have in macro1

```
Public rng1 As Range
' ...
Set rng1 = Range("K10").Offset(i, 0)
```

I would like to change position to 1 cell to the right using macro2.

Something like this:

```
Set rng1 = rng1.Offset(0, 1)
```

Is that possible or is there another way?

Whole code:

```
Public rng1 As Range

Sub tert()

Dim rng As Range
Dim rnga As Range
Dim i As Integer
i = 0

Do
    DoEvents
    Set rng1 = Range("K10").Offset(i, 0)
    Set rng = Range("J10").Offset(i, 0)
    Set rnga = Union(rng, rng1)
    rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    rng1.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    rng.Offset(-4, 0).clear
    rng1.Offset(-1, 0).clear
    i = i + 1

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))

    If Not Intersect(Range("A30:Z30"), rnga) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If rng.Offset(1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then Exit Sub

Loop

End Sub


Sub rightx()
    Set rng1 = rng1.Offset(0, 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try it?  What happened when you tried what you're proposing?  This is one of those situations were the time it took to ask, you'd already have the answer.  Now, if you tried it and it didn't' work, that's a separate issue...

Comment: let me tell you a secret, yes, it works :)  and you could have just used `Debug.Print rng1.Address` and see it in the immediate window

Comment: yup I've tried and what happens is ... completely nothing :)

Comment: @Pawel run the code in my answer below and see what you get in your immediate window

Comment: If you do not initialyze `i` it will be equal to `0` so you will have `Set rng1 = Range("K10").Offset(0, 0)` which will be the same range `K10`; maybe that is the problem? :)

Comment: I've just added the whole code to my question to give you guys a better view

Comment: @Pawel what is your code trying to achieve ? what is the logics of the `Do` loop ? when does it exit ? also, in your code, you never call `Sub rightx`

Comment: @ShaiRado that's the whole point - it does't call `sub rightx` because I would like to execute `sub rightx` myself and by that change range of rng1 inside the loop.

Comment: @ShaiRado the code simply makes certain range of cells "travel" down the worksheet. What I'm trying to achive is to change position of those "traveling" cells by 1 column to the right. ( Like in tetris :) )

Comment: @Pawel you want to change `rng1` inside the loop ? and get rid of the other `Sub rightx` ?

Comment: @ShaiRado By running `sub rightx` I would like to change rng1 inside the loop ( while `sub tert()` is running)

Comment: @Pawel so add a `Call rightx` inside your `Do` loop, but when and how do you exit this `Loop` ?

Comment: I don't want to `call rightx` because I don't want  `rightx` to run automatically. I want the `rng1` to change only when I run the `rightx` at specific time.

Comment: @ShaiRado you there? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123767/discussion-between-shai-rado-and-pawel).

Answer (score 1):

Just to demonstarte how it works:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DynamicRange()

Dim rng1    As Range
Dim i       As Long

' let's take 1 as the offset value
i = 1

Set rng1 = Range("K10").Offset(i, 0)
Debug.Print rng1.Address  ' << you get $K$11

Set rng1 = rng1.Offset(0, i)
Debug.Print rng1.Address  ' << you get $L$11    

End Sub
```

**Edit 1**: Put the code in 2 seperate `Sub`s, moved the `rng1` declaration outside the Sub and declared it as `Public`

```
Option Explicit

' moved the rng1 declaration outside the Sub and declared it as Publi
Public rng1    As Range

Sub Call2Macros()

Call DynamicRange
Call DynamicRange2

End Sub

Sub DynamicRange()

Dim i       As Long

i = 1
Set rng1 = Range("K10").Offset(i, 0)  
Debug.Print rng1.Address  ' << you get $K$11

End Sub

Sub DynamicRange2()

Dim i       As Long

i = 2
Set rng1 = rng1.Offset(0, i)
Debug.Print rng1.Address  ' << you get $M$11

End Sub
```

Comment: OK, but I need this: `Set rng1 = rng1.Offset(0, i)` to be placed in another macro, and I would like to execute this while 1st macro (loop) is running

Comment: I've just added the whole code to my question to give you guys a better view

Comment: @Pawel did my code work for you ? cause now you uploaded your code, which is a totaly different post, since you are asking us to debug it, without understand what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: I'm little bit confused right now. The code that I've pasted does not work. Your code works just fine, but when I adapt it to my code if just doesn't.    I guess I asked my question wrong at first place. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example. By declaring your range outside of your procedure, it can be used any sub in your module

```
Dim rng As Range

Sub test1()
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 2
        Set rng = Range("K10").Offset(i, 0)
        Debug.Print rng.Address
        OffsetRange
        Debug.Print rng.Address
    Next i
End Sub

Sub OffsetRange()
    Set rng = rng.Offset(0, 1)
End Sub
```

This is not a particularly useful piece of code - all it does is offset and debug that position. However, it should illustrate one way you could get around your problem